# associating two separate arrays for itinerary system

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I am trying to build a travel itinerary system. The user selects the dates of travel, and then may add items to each day.

I have an array of dates, stored in a session in the format:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => '2012-08-25',
    (int) 1 => '2012-08-26',
    (int) 2 => '2012-08-27'
)
```

They will then choose attractions, which I wish to store in an array in the format:

```
array(
(int) 0 => array(
    'Attraction' => array(
        'attraction_id' =>'1',
        'name' => 'Place One',

    )
),
(int) 1 => array(
    'Attraction' => array(
        'attraction_id' => '2',
        'name' => 'Place Two',

    )
),
```

I'd like to be able to output:

- 2012-08-25

  - Place One
  - Place Two
- 2012-08-26

  - nothing here yet!
- 2012-08-27

  - nothing here yet!

So, each item of the first array contains an array of items, if that makes sense. I am struggling with the logic of associating the keys of the `days` array with the `items` array.

I looked at `array_merge` but that doesn't seem to do what I need.

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: Your example is not consistent with the rules given. place two should be in 2012-08-26

Answer (score 1):

This code does exactly what you ask. Unfortunately, I fear your question  doesn't reflect your aim given the example. Using keys to link data will led to 1-1 relationship, where as you seem to need a 1-n. You should have a foreign key field in the attraction array, like date_id.

```
$array= array();

foreach($dates as $date_key=>$date){
   $array[$date]=array();
   foreach($attractions as $attraction_key=>$attraction){
        if($date_key==$attraction_key){
           $array[$date][]=$attraction['Attraction']['name'];
         }   
     }
}
```

Comment: That code is incredibly hard to read with the absolute minimum of whitespace you've included.

Comment: it reads fine to me. That makes sense + I get what you mean about requiring a 1-n relationship, looking back my sample code wasn't 100% clear. I will see how i get on with this, thank you